# I don't understand how create RoleManager by Ninject in my app, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ninject

Please ask me, How add a binding in the Ninject.Web.Common?

I have the entity for the Role

```
public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{
    public AppRole() : base() { }

    public AppRole(string name)
        : base(name)
    { }
}
```

and the manager

```
public class AppRoleManager : RoleManager<AppRole>
{
    public AppRoleManager(RoleStore<AppRole> store) : base(store)
    { }
}
```

i want that the creating method are doing in Ninject like i did the UserManager and SignUpManager

my Ninject common

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));

        kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>();
        kernel.Bind<RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>>().ToSelf();

    }

kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>();
    kernel.Bind<RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>>().ToSelf();
```

I change the binding which where wrong to

```
kernel.Bind<AppRoleManager>().ToSelf();
        kernel.Bind<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>>().To<RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>();
```

and the problem in constructor is off. (thank you Alexander)

but the problem in view

[image]

my controller Didn't have any error when i compile the app. However in return view [image: I took it]

private IUserManagerRepository userManager;
        private readonly AppRoleManager userRole;

```
    public RoleController(IUserManagerRepository userManager, AppRoleManager userRole)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    // GET: Role
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(userRole.Roles);
    }
```

And my view

```
@using Domain.IdentityManager
@using Domain.Entities
@model IEnumerable<AppRole>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">Roles</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Пользователи</th>
        <th style="min-width: 150px"></th>
    </tr>
        @foreach (AppRole role in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>
                    @if (role.Users == null || role.Users.Count == 0)
                    {
                        @: Нет пользователей в этой роли
                    }
                    else
                    {

                }
                </td>
        }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error you have to make *consistent accessibility* of `RoleController` constructor and its parameter type. Since constructor is `public` its parameters have to be `public` as well. Compiler complaining about `AppRoleManager<IdentityRole>` so we need to look at it. Apparently `AppRoleManager` is `public` and it looks like `IdentityRole` is only not `public` type here. So update its declaration

```
public class IdentityRole //
```

Comment: i change it but in view have the error can you watch the question again i edit him

Comment: @remk93 The exception explicitly states that it is something wrong with connection string in your `DbContext`. Check connection string, and also check if such database exists.

Comment: yes, problem that something delete all the tables, interesting why, before roles i checked and it was work, well actually thank you for helping!!